# How to determine sum of two numbers from a list

Tags: prolog

Trying to determine if two numbers in list equal a given value.

I have read through numerous questions and most of the lists.pl from the swi-prolog documentation. I can determine how to find out if the sum of all items in the list equal a given value, but not if any two of the items equal the given value.

```
sum([ ],0). %Pretty sure this makes the list(?)
sum([H|T],Sum) :- sum(T, Temp), Sum is Temp + H. %recursively adds the numbers
%maybe my base case is off
```

```
?- sum([1,2,3,4], 10).
```

Returns true because the sum of the list items is 10, but...

```
?- sum([1,2,3,4], 6).
```

returns false, and I need it to return true because 4 + 2 = 6.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly a case for DCGs:

```
sum_of_2_items(Xs, N) :-
   phrase(( ..., [A], ..., [B], ...), Xs),
   N is A+B.

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Or, minimally more efficient:

```
sum_of_2_items(Xs, N) :-
   phrase(( ..., [A], ..., [B], {N is A+B}, ...), Xs).
```

Answer (score 0):

`append/3` is your friend when it comes to decomposing lists.

Try something like this:

```
sum_of_2_items(L,N) :-
  take2( L, X, Y ),
  N =:= X + Y
  .

take2( L , X , Y ) :-
  append( Pfx, [X|Sfx], L ),
  gety( Pfx, Sfx , Y )
  .

gety( L, _, Y ) :- gety( L, Y ).
gety( _, L, Y ) :- gety( L, Y ).

gety( [Y|_],  Y ).
gety( [_|Ys], Y ) :- gety( Ys, Y ).
```

Comment: Or even `take2ordered(XsYs,X,Y) :- append(_,[X|Ys],XsYs),append(_,[Y|_],Ys).`

Comment: @jschimpf ... and as far as I can tell, `append(_, [X|Ys], L)` is _exactly_ the same as `select(X, L, Ys)`?

Comment: @User9213 not exactly, with append Ys is the rest of the list after X, with select it's the whole list without X. That's why the select-based solutions are a bit inefficient, they look at each value pair twice (in different order).

Comment: @jschimpf I understand now¸ thank you! So basically using append you add a positional "constraint" on the elements you are picking -- definitely useful. If you don't write your comment as an answer I'll do it ;-)

Comment: @User9213 go ahead ;)

Comment: @jschimpf ah, not worth the effort. false killed the thread with his ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook predicate for this is `select/3`. It is a true relation between a list, an element in the list, and the rest of the list.

```
?- select(X, [1,2,3,4], Rest).
X = 1,
Rest = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = 2,
Rest = [1, 3, 4] ;
X = 3,
Rest = [1, 2, 4] ;
X = 4,
Rest = [1, 2, 3].
```

So you just use it twice:

```
sum_of_two(List, Sum) :-
    select(X, List, L0),
    select(Y, L0, _),
    plus(X, Y, Sum).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be more general, check if a number is the sum of numbers of a list.

There are two base cases :

N is a member of the list

```
sum(L, N) :- 
   member(L, N).
```

N can be the sum of two numbers :

```
sum(L, N) :-
  select(A, L, L1),
  select(B, L1, _),
  N is A+B.
```

Now the general case :

```
sum(L, N):-
    select(A, L, L1),
    N1 is N-A,
    N1 >= 0,
    sum(L1, N1).
```

Notice that this code only works for positive numbers
There may be a lot of solutions, so we can just check that there is a solution with **once/1**.
So :

```
check_sum(L, N) :-
    once(sum(L, N)).

sum(L, N):-
    select(N, L, _).

sum(L, N) :-
    select(A, L, L1),
    select(B, L1, _),
    N =:= A+B.

sum(L, N):-
    select(A, L, L1),
    N1 is N-A,
    N1 >= 0,
    sum(L1, N1).
```